# Neo4j exception when creating relationships

Tags: java, neo4j

I am creating all nodes, then adding all relationships. All nodes are stored in a HashMap containing the String name as a key and node as a value, so I can get to nodes easily to create relationships.

```
    for(Map.Entry<String[], Integer> entry: company_counts_backward.entrySet()){
        String[] node_names  = entry.getKey();
        String company_from = node_names[0];
        String company_to = node_names[1];

        int count = entry.getValue();

        Node companyFromNode = nodes_created.get(company_from);
        Node companyToNode = nodes_created.get(company_to);
        Relationship relationship = companyFromNode.createRelationshipTo(companyToNode, Relations.WORKED_AT);
        relationship.setProperty("relationship-type", "knows");
        relationship.setProperty("length", count);
    }
```

Please note, this for loop is surrounded by a 
`Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx();`
`tx.finish();`

Issue is that when creating a relationship, I seem to be getting a `Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException` thrown.

The full error trace is as follows:

```
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getCurrentTransaction(PersistenceManager.java:284)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:249)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.currentKernelTransactionForReading(PersistenceManager.java:230)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.transaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:53)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.instance(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:47)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.createRelationshipTo(NodeProxy.java:406)
```

Can anyone please identify and point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Place any code dealing with the database inside the `try-with-resources` block:

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
  Node n1 = db.createNode();
  Node n2 = db.createNode();
  n1.createRelationshipTo(n2, REL_TYPE);
  tx.success(); // This is important!
}
```

Note that sometimes (e.g. when performing read-only operations) you don't have to call `tx.success()`, because there is nothing to commit.

Refer to [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions.html) for more information about transaction management.

P.S. I do understand that you pointed out that you know about the necessity of transaction management, so I don't just repeat your words, I emphasize that a) `Transaction#finish()` is deprecated and should not be used, therefore I suggest using modern approach, and b) before closing the transaction one should always commit changes if they have been made.